# Laravel redirect()->route() not working correctly (view is in the old state never updated)

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, model-view-controller, request

I have a very strange issue in one of my projects. I have a redirect route in one of my controllers that redirects and opens a route but does not work.

I know this sounds vague and I will do my best to explain. I have a view with a some href's on it that sends a get request to controller this controller calls a handler and the handler inserts some records and then the controller redirects back to the original route.

At the moment when i click on it the get request fires the records get inserted correctly and i get back on the originial page but here is the problem the original page is still in the old state and not updated. I have to refresh the page manually to see the changes take effect. I can click the same href a hunderd times without anything updating in the view.

To make it even worse the same exact codes works fine on the local development environment and on the staging evironment this just happens on the production environment.

**My view:**

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('title', 'Trajecten')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
       @if (Session::has('status'))
          <div class="alert alert-success">
              <ul>
                  <li>{{Session::get('status')}}</li>
              </ul>
          </div>
        @endif
         @if (count($errors) > 0) 
              <div class="alert alert-danger">
                  <ul>
                      @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                      <li>{{$error}}</li>
                      @endforeach
                  </ul>
              </div>
            @endif
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
         <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contactModal">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-orange pull-right">
            Meld nieuwe inkoop behoefte
          </button>
        </a>
        <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Product/dienst</th>
                <th>Geïnteresseerd</th>
                <th>Deelnemen t/m</th>
                <th>Informatie</th>
                <th>Deelnemen</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          @foreach($trajects as $traject)
            <tr>
              <td>{{$traject->name}}</td>
              <td>{{$traject->deelnemers->count() + $traject->participants}}</td>
              <td>{{date('d-m-Y', strtotime($traject->tot))}}</td>
              <td>Klik <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#trajectmodal{{$traject->id}}" onclick="log(10,2,{{$traject->id}})">hier</a> voor meer informatie</td>
              <td>@if(in_array($traject->id, $usertrajects))  U bent geregistreerd als geïnteresseerde @else Klik <a href="{{ route('traject.participate', ['id' => $traject->id])}}">hier</a> voor deelname @endif</td>
            </tr>
          @endforeach
        </table>
    </div>
    </div>
    @foreach($trajects as $traject)
     <div class="modal fade" id="trajectmodal{{$traject->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Meer informatie voor {{$traject->name}}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  {!!$traject->description!!}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer text-center">
            @if($traject->conditie != "")<a target="__blank" href="{{$traject->conditie}}" onclick="log(11,2,{{$traject->id}})"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left btn-orange">Conditie</button></a>@endif
            @if($traject->product != "")<a target="__blank" href="{{$traject->product}}" onclick="log(12,2,{{$traject->id}})"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-orange">Product</button></a>@endif
            @if($traject->leverancier != "")<a target="__blank" href="{{$traject->leverancier}}" onclick="log(13,2,{{$traject->id}})"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-orange">Leverancier</button></a>@endif
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    @endforeach
</div>

<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="contactModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="gridSystemModalLabel">Meldpunt inkoop behoefte</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="meldinkoopbehoefte" method="post">
          {!! csrf_field() !!}
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="subject" class="col-sm-3 text-left control-label">Inkoop behoefte</label>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Onderwerp" value="">
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="message" class="col-sm-3 text-left control-label">Bericht</label>
              <div class="col-sm-9">
                  <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Bericht" name="message"></textarea>
              </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" onclick="javascript:$('#meldinkoopbehoefte').submit()" class="btn btn-primary btn-orange">Verstuur</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
@endsection
```

**My method in the controller**

Changing the route to another page i see the changes take effect like the session flash. So i am suspecting my view at this point.

```
public function participate($id){
    if(TrajectHandler::participate($id)){
        Session::flash('status', 'Uw interesse of voorstel is ontvangen');
    }
    //Changing the route to another page i see the changes take effect.
    //So i am suspecting my view at this point.
    return redirect()->route('traject.index'); 
}
```

**The index method in the controller**

```
public function index(){

        $trajects = TrajectHandler::getTrajects();
        $userTrajects = TrajectHandler::getUserTrajects();

        foreach ($trajects as $traject) {

            if (!is_null(ViewedUserTraject::where('user_id', Auth::id())
                ->where('traject_id', $traject->id)->first()))
                continue;

            $viewedTraject = new ViewedUserTraject();
            $viewedTraject->user_id = Auth::id();
            $viewedTraject->traject_id = $traject->id;
            $viewedTraject->save();
        }

        return view('traject.index', [
            'trajects' => $trajects,
            'usertrajects' => $userTrajects
        ]);
    }
```

**Another method in the controlller**

I decided to add this method in the question as it is basically the exact same thing but does work.

```
    public function suggestTraject(ContactRequest $request){
        Mailer::inkoopBehoefteMail(Auth::user(), $request->subject, $request->message);
        Session::flash('status', 'Inkoop behoeften verstuurd.');
        return redirect()->route('traject.index');
    }
```

**The participate method in the TrajectHandler**

```
    public static function participate($id){
        $count = TrajectUser::where('user_id' , Auth::id())->where('traject_id', $id)->get();

        if (count($count) == 0) {
            $traject = new TrajectUser;
            $traject->traject_id = $id;
            $traject->user_id = Auth::id();
            if($traject->save()){
                Logger::log(Auth::id(),5,2,$id);
                Mailer::newTrajectUser(Auth::user(), Traject::find($id));
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
```

**My routes**

```
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'traject'], function(){
        Route::get('', ['as' =>  'traject.index' , 'uses' => 'User\TrajectController@index']);
        Route::post('', ['as' =>  'traject.index' , 'uses' => 'User\TrajectController@suggestTraject']);
        Route::get('participate/{id}', ['as' =>  'traject.participate' , 'uses' => 'User\TrajectController@participate']);
    });
```

Comment: Can you post the code for `TrajectController::index()` ?

Comment: @Jerodev Added it in the question.

Comment: Try this `return redirect()->route('traject');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it had something to do with caching.

Adding the following headers in my routes file fixed the issued for me.

```
header('Expires: Sun, 01 Jan 2014 00:00:00 GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE);
header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

Comment: Where did you put this??

Answer (score 0):

Does the php version on the production environment meets the minimum required php version for Laravel? For Laravel 5.2 you need php 5.5.9. See the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2)

Comment: phpversion() returns 5.5.34